How do I batch move all files from subdirectories into a main directory while renaming overwrites
I downloaded all files from a website from the Internet Archive. Now I have a directory with over 1000 subdirectories labeled by date archived. Each of these subdirectories contain a few files.

I want to move all of these files in the subdirectories into one directory, but some of these files have the same name (because they are different versions of the same file at different points in time).
I want to append the name of the directory the file comes from to the filename only if it's a duplicate filename (instead of overwriting the file in the new directory).

Is there a way to do this?

Sounds like you would rather want to rename files with that suffix when they're found in more than one directory. Maybe something like:
perl -se '
  for (<*/*>) {
    m{(.*)/(.*)}s;
    push @{$dirs{$2}}, $1;
  }
  while (($name, $dirs) = each %dirs) {
    for $dir (@$dirs) {
      $dest = "$target/$name";
      $dest .= ".$dir" if @$dirs > 1;
      rename "$dir/$name", $dest or
        die "$dir/$name -> $dest: $!\n";
    }
  }' -- -target=/path/to/dest/dir

Note that $target must not be one of those subdirectories if it's not empty to start with, or you'd need to adapt the <*/*> pattern to make sure it excludes its files.
Also note that hidden files are excluded. You could change the pattern to <{,..?,.[!.]}*/{,..?,.[!.]}*> if you wanted them.

Thank you for this! I’ve never used perl before. If I’m not mistaken, I just have to change the target path in this script, make a .pl of it in my directory, and run it in there?

@Siena, no you'd just run that command as shown (adapting the path of the target to your need) from any Bourne-like shell (would also work in rc-like shells or fish, not csh/tcsh). You can also dump that in a shell script taking the target dir as argument, or change it to a perl script if you like.

Use mv's --backup option, as described in man mv, and, with  "thousands" of dirs/files, use find and xargs. Something like (Untested):
find . -mindepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
  xargs -0 -r mv --target-directory=$PWD --backup=numbered

Then, to remove the now empty dirs, take advantage of rmdir's refusal to delete non-empty directories, do (Untested):
find . -depth -type d -print0 | \
  xargs -0 -r rmdir

